# Clojure: how do I print the results of an SQL query?

Tags: oracle, clojure

Let's say I want to execute the following queries:
(select * from table)
(select count(*) from table)

http://clojuredocs.org/clojure_contrib/clojure.contrib.sql/with-query-results

How do I put all these into a vector so that I can print out the results?
Give specific examples please.

Comment: Why is it that when I execute this query (sql/with-query-results rows ["SELECT count(*) from tableName"] (doseq [record rows] (println (vals record)))), the print value is "116M", what does the 'M' mean? Is this a string value?

Comment: The M at the end of the number identifies the result as belonging to BigDecimal (http://clojure.org/data_structures).  Oracle usually treats all numbers like decimal, so the count from the database comes back like that.  The results look correct for the query.  What have you tried to put the values into a vector?

Answer (score 5):

The `clojure.contrib.sql` library is deprecated and the documentation you linked to is outdated for the current version of the library, now called `clojure.java.jdbc`. Updated documentation for that library can be found here:

- Community maintained [`java.jdbc` documentation](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/home.html)
- Auto-generated [reference documentation](http://clojure.github.io/java.jdbc/)
- The [Github repository for java.jdbc](https://github.com/clojure/java.jdbc/), showing current dependency information

To answer your specific question, you would want to use the `query` function now and you'll find [detailed documentation on running queries](http://clojure-doc.org/articles/ecosystem/java_jdbc/using_sql.html) on the community maintained site. What you get back from `query` is a fully-realized sequence of maps, which solves the problem I think you're running into (that `with-query-result` returns a lazy sequence and so if you don't fully realize it inside that macro call, you get an exception about operating on a closed connection).

The `query` function can process the result set in more flexible ways via `:as-arrays?`, `:row-fn`, and `:result-set-fn` which make it a lot easier to work with than the old library you mentioned.